# Not redirecting to home/ login page on the basis of authentication token validation in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have set up the main.dart file as below like this to redirect to MyNavogationBar() if the authentication token is valid, if not valid then redirect to Login() page When I am using an emulator this is working fine to my emulation device. Even when I am using an external device with USB, at that time it is also working but when I am using build apk file and installing that apk file to a device, this is not working. Then it is redirecting to a blank page.
where is the any issue? or how can I do this redirecting part in an efficient way?

main.dart

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isLoggedIn = false;
  late Future<dynamic> _futureAuthVerify;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // checkToken();
    _futureAuthVerify = Authentication().verifyToken();
  }

  // Future<void> checkToken() async {
  //   var token = await Authentication().verifyToken();
  //   if (token.statusCode == 200) {
  //     setState(() {
  //     isLoggedIn = true;
  //   });
  //   } else {
  //     isLoggedIn = false;
  //   }
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _futureAuthVerify,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data!.statusCode == 200) {
              return MaterialApp(
                home: MyNavigationBar(),
              );
            } else {
              return MaterialApp(
                home: Login(),
              );
            }
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('${snapshot.error}');
          }
          return Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Center(
                  child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: AppColor.primaryBlue)));
        });
  }
}
```

verifyToken function :

```
Future<dynamic> verifyToken() async {
    var token = await Utils().getToken('access');
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(ApiEndpoints.verifyTokenUrl),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(<String, String?>{
          'token': token
        }),
      );
      return response;
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      return e;
    } on Error catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e);
    }
  }
```

getToken function:

```
    final _storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    Future<String?> getToken(key) async {
        return await _storage.read(
          key: key,
          iOptions: _getIOSOptions(),
          aOptions: _getAndroidOptions(),
        );
      }
```

MyNavigationBar()

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nextgen_myhealth_patients/screens/appointment.dart';
import 'package:nextgen_myhealth_patients/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:nextgen_myhealth_patients/screens/messege.dart';
import 'package:nextgen_myhealth_patients/screens/more.dart';
import 'package:nextgen_myhealth_patients/screens/prescription.dart';
import 'package:nextgen_myhealth_patients/utility/styles/colors.dart';

class MyNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyNavigationBar({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyNavigationBar> createState() => _MyNavigationBarState();
}

class _MyNavigationBarState extends State<MyNavigationBar> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  Map<int, GlobalKey<NavigatorState>> navigatorKeys = {
     0: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
     1: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
     2: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
     3: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
     4: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
  };

  static const List<Widget> _screenOptions = <Widget>[
    Home(),
    Appointments(),
    Prescription(),
    Messege(),
    More()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        // body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        //     value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        //     child: Center(
        //       child: _screenOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
        //     )),
        body: buildNavigator(),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(15), topLeft: Radius.circular(15)),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black38, spreadRadius: 0, blurRadius: 2),
              ],
            ),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                topRight: Radius.circular(15),
              ),
              child: BottomNavigationBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                selectedItemColor: AppColor.primaryBlue,
                selectedIconTheme:
                    const IconThemeData(color: AppColor.primaryBlue, size: 20),
                unselectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(size: 20),
                // showUnselectedLabels: false,
                selectedFontSize: 12,
                unselectedFontSize: 12,
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
                onTap: _onItemTapped,
                items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month), label: 'Appointments'),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.medication), label: 'Prescriptions'),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.email), label: 'Messege'),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.menu), label: 'More'),
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
  buildNavigator() {
     return Navigator(
       key: navigatorKeys[_selectedIndex],
       onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings){
         return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => _screenOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex));
       },
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your MyNavigationBar code?

Comment: which one of if-else is getting triggered in your case?

Comment: @Rahul I am not sure. it is giving a blank page.

Comment: @Saad please check the edited version

Answer (score 1):

```
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
    
      final String title;
    
      @override
      State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      bool isLoggedIn = false;
      late Future<dynamic> _futureAuthVerify;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        // checkToken();
        _futureAuthVerify = Authentication().verifyToken();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder(
            future: _futureAuthVerify,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
    
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                if (snapshot.data!.statusCode == 200) {
                  return const MyNavigationBar();
                } else {
                  return const Login();
                }
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }else{
                return Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: Colors.black45)));
              }
    
            });
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on it a little bit? It will be helpful for me. Though I have got an idea from your code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).